# Hadoop hdfs datanode unable to find namenode

Tags: hadoop, networking, hbase, opentsdb

I'm new to hadoop and I recently deployed 2 distributed hadoop system to run by opentsdb. Host A is master together with slave, and host B is a slavenode.
Editing /etc/hosts in machine A:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.94.212.144   node1
10.48.22.52     node2
```

I don't have the root permission of machine B and can't modify B's /etc/hosts, so in B's core-site.xml,　I wrote:

```
<property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://10.94.212.144:49000</value>
</property>
```

while in A fs.default.name is node1:49000
A is the master and A,B both are slaves, when I ran start-dfs.sh,namenode,datanode1 starts normally, however datanode2 failed to start with the error:

```
2016-11-15 12:42:43,103 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /10.94.212.144:49000. Already tried 0 time(s).
2016-11-15 12:42:44,106 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /10.94.212.144:49000. Already tried 1 time(s).
2016-11-15 12:42:45,109 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /10.94.212.144:49000. Already tried 2 time(s).
2016-11-15 12:42:46,112 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /10.94.212.144:49000. Already tried 3 time(s).
2016-11-15 12:42:47,115 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /10.94.212.144:49000. Already tried 4 time(s).
2016-11-15 12:42:48,117 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /10.94.212.144:49000. Already tried 5 time(s).
2016-11-15 12:42:49,120 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /10.94.212.144:49000. Already tried 6 time(s).
2016-11-15 12:42:50,123 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /10.94.212.144:49000. Already tried 7 time(s).
2016-11-15 12:42:51,125 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /10.94.212.144:49000. Already tried 8 time(s).
2016-11-15 12:42:52,128 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /10.94.212.144:49000. Already tried 9 time(s).
```

Is that the network problems? But it's ok when I use ssh the connect A and B with each other. What else reasons may it be? It's been bothering me for several day...

Comment: Try `telnet 10.94.212.144 49000` from node2. you might have firewall issues.

Comment: Thank you, it came out to be the network problem